# jQuery to prepend URL in img src attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just need a jQuery snippet to do the prepend in img src , i.e

```
<img src='/img/picture1.jpg' />
```

The code snippet jQuery is to prepend this url

```
http://cdn.something.com/
```

so after the snippet jQuery, it becomes like

```
<img src='http://cdn.something.com/img/picture1.jpg' />
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

so far I wrote something like

```
$().ready(function(){
     var cdn ='http://cdn.something.com';
   $('img').attrib('src', cdn);
```

});

However it is replaced the src rather than pre

Answer (score 8):

it's not really jQuery related, anyway you could do it with `.attr()`<sup>[what is that?](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)</sup>:

```
$('img').attr('src', function(index, src) {
     return 'http://cdn.something.com' + src;
});
```

This would affect all of your `<img>` nodes in your markup and replace the `src`.

Anyway, I'm not so sure that this is a great idea. At the time  the`DOMready` event fires, a browser might already have tried to access the `old` source attribute. If you must do this in Javascript, it's probably a better idea to store the `path info` within a custom `data attribute` so a browser is not tempted to load the image. This could look like:

HTML

```
<img src='' data-path='/img/picture1.jpg' />
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $('img').attr('src', function(index, src) {
       return 'http://cdn.something.com' + this.getAttribute('data-path');
    });
});
```

This should do it. You could replace `this.getAttribute()` by `$(this).data('path')` since jQuery parses those `data attributes` into it's "node" data hash. But this would create another jQuery object, which really is unecessary at this point.

Comment: shouldn't it be `return 'http://cdn.something.com' + src;` , coz the src of the img tag starts with a / already

Comment: @dbwebtek: You're welcome! you might want to accept an answer if you consider it as useful and correct.

Comment: @jAndy Can you explain why the browser is not tempted to load the image? Because it sees the image-tag, why wouldn't it try to render it?

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
$.ready(function() {
    $('img').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('src', cdn + $(this).attr('src'));
    });
});
```

However I'm not sure it is the good solution for using a CDN, as the browser will have already tried to load the images from your server at the time the script will be called.

You should do this on the server side instead.

Comment: yeah you are correct , browser quickly loading img before the script as the script wait for DOM ready...I can see the FLASH in transition time...Thanks for comment

Comment: Good Job Man :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending what your specific problem is, you might be able to sort out this problem with a [base](http://htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/base/) tag, but I assume you will only want this on images, but changing the src once the page has loaded will make the images reload? IF the images don't exist in the current location you will need to change the src attribute before the page is loaded (server side).