# Override href with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, overriding, href

I have a lot of links with this structure:

```
<a class="myclass" href="http://externaldomain.com">Anchor Text</a>
```

I'd like to put something before the url in the href attribute to change the structure in this way:

```
<a class="myclass" href="http://internaldomain.com/http://externaldomain.com">Anchor Text</a>
```

I think jquery is perfect to do this, but I don't know how. Can you help me?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/each/ http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Do you have any code that you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.myclass').each(function(){this.href = "http://internaldomain.com/"+this.href});
```

Answer (score 0):

`href` is an attribute of `a` element, so you can change it using [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method on elements with class `myclass`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a modifying callback to the `attr` method:

```
$('[href^=http:]').attr('href',function(i,str) {
  return "http://internaldomain.com/"+str;
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you are missing the closing brace after `http:` :p

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.myclass').attr('href', function(i, href) {
     return 'http://internaldomain.com/' + href;
});
```

Source:
[jQuery to prepend URL in img src attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815398/jquery-to-prepend-url-in-img-src-attribute)